# fputc / fprintf fails to write to my file

Tags: c, file

I am supposed to write a program that takes a text file (that contains plain text) and corrects the following mistakes (involving the punctuation):

```
Hello , there! --> Hello, there!
Hello ,there! --> Hello, there!
A sentence. this should be capitalized --> A sentence. This should be capitalized
```

The algorithm i've come up with is the following:
I loop through the text file line by line, and pass each line to a mistake finder function. This function detects the above (1st and 2nd) mistakes and stores a double number in the mistakes array. The integer part shows the position where the mistake begins and the decimal part shows the type of mistake found.

For example if i passed `"Hello , there!"` as an argument, the double that would be stored in the array is 5.1 since the mistake begins in the 5th character of the string and 0.1 because it's the 1st type of mistake.

Similarly `"Hello ,there!"` would store 5.2 in the array (2nd type of mistake).
After locating the mistakes, a piece of code writes the new corrected line in a different file.

```
FILE *src, *dst; //source file, destination file
int ptr; //shows how many mistakes were found in the line 
src = fopen((const char*)filename, "r"); //opening both files
dst = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
char array[1024];
double mistakes[1024];
double mistakeType, position;
int i, j, pos = 0, capitalNeeded = 1; //capitalNeeded shows whether the next letter should be capitalized


while(fgets(array, 1024, src)!=NULL){ //taking the content of the file line by line
    puts(array);
    ptr = findMistakes(array, mistakes); //the mistakes of the current line are located, and their types are defined

    for(i=0; i<ptr; i++){ //looping through the mistakes
        if(capitalNeeded && isalpha(array[pos])){
            array[pos] = toupper(array[pos]);
            capitalNeeded = 0;
        }
        mistakeType = modf(mistakes[i], &position); //position will be of type int.0000..
        for(j=pos; j<position; j++){
            if(array[j] == '.' || array[j] == '?' ||array[j] == '!'){ //testing if a capital letter is needed
                capitalNeeded = 1;
            }
            if(capitalNeeded && isalpha(array[j])){
                array[j] = toupper(array[j]);
                capitalNeeded = 0;
            }
        }
        pos = j+1; //pos becomes the last j+1, basically shows the next character to be read from the array

        if(mistakeType == 0.1){ //if mistake was of type 1
            //then pos points to a space character ' '. The space is bypassed and the next 
            //character is placed in the file
            fprintf(dst, "%c", array[pos+1]); //which is a punctuation character
            fprintf(dst, "%c", array[pos+2]); //then a space is placed
            pos += 3; //the next character to be read and placed becomes pos+3
        }
        else{ //only 2 type of mistakes exist, so if it's not of type 1 then it's of type 2
            //In a type 2 mistake the punctuation mark is attached to the next letter
            //pos currently points to a space character ' ', and pos+1 to a punctuation mark.
            fprintf(dst, "%c", array[pos+1]);
            fprintf(dst, "%c", array[pos]);
            pos += 2; //the next character to be read and placed becomes pos+2
        }
    }
    fprintf(dst, "%c", '\n'); //the line is changed
    pos = 0; //pos is reset, and readied for the processing of the next line


}
```

However, i haven't been able to tell if my algorithm works because `fputc` won't work. There's no error in the compilation, but the new file is empty. I understand that `fputc()` takes `int` arguments, so i tried using `fprintf(dst, "%c", array[...]);`but that yielded the exact same results. I searched but couldn't find the answer, any help is appreciated...

Comment: You shoud just use an array of `struct { int pos; int mis; }`. `pos` would be the position, and `mis` would be one of two `enum` values, that represents the type of mistake

Comment: @stackptr Indeed that would be better, but i am a beginner and not very familiar with structs as of yet... However that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: just debuggg, gdb is your friend,) Write up simple example on a paper, so you know all vars at each step and compare with what you get. You'll be able to pin point the line where it goes wrong, Then we might help.

Comment: Don't use `double` to store two integers. It's not a clever trick. If you need two integers, have two `int` variables.

Comment: @AlPimenov The IDE i am using is kinda lame (dev c++). By the time i press the debug button the program instantly crushes. So i've used printf's to do the job and i've concluded that fputc/fprintf are not working :/

Comment: @Alan compile your file on the terminal with -g flag. gcc -g <your file name>. then type gdb <your exec.fiel> then put breakpoint at main: type s for one step and p <var name to display it>. Your program crushes when you press debug most likely because you don't have any break point so it just runs it.

Comment: @AlPimenov debug --> You have not enabled debugging info (-g) and/or stripped it from the executable (-s) in compiler options. Do you want to correct this now? --> yes --> dev c++ has stopped working...

Comment: Until you have fixed your debugging environment, you should stop trying to write software - you don't have the necessary tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error from [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) about your code.

```
   ==20508== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
    ==20508==    at 0x4EA7A9E: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
    ==20508==    by 0x400D0E: main (in /home/dac/ClionProjects/replace/a.out)
    ==20508== 
    ==20508== Invalid read of size 4
    ==20508==    at 0x4EA7A9E: fgets (iofgets.c:47)
    ==20508==    by 0x400D0E: main (in /home/dac/ClionProjects/replace/a.out)
    ==20508==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I suggest you use string replacement. I hope this example can help you.

**temp.txt**

> Hello , there! Hello ,there! A sentence. this should be capitalized

(we're going to manipulate the space as a string and write it to file file.txt)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// You must free the result if result is non-NULL.
char *str_replace(char *orig, char *rep, char *with) {
    char *result; // the return string
    char *ins;    // the next insert point
    char *tmp;    // varies
    int len_rep;  // length of rep
    int len_with; // length of with
    int len_front; // distance between rep and end of last rep
    int count;    // number of replacements

    if (!orig)
        return NULL;
    if (!rep)
        rep = "";
    len_rep = strlen(rep);
    if (!with)
        with = "";
    len_with = strlen(with);

    ins = orig;
    for (count = 0; tmp = strstr(ins, rep); ++count) {
        ins = tmp + len_rep;
    }

    // first time through the loop, all the variable are set correctly
    // from here on,
    //    tmp points to the end of the result string
    //    ins points to the next occurrence of rep in orig
    //    orig points to the remainder of orig after "end of rep"
    tmp = result = malloc(strlen(orig) + (len_with - len_rep) * count + 1);

    if (!result)
        return NULL;

    while (count--) {
        ins = strstr(orig, rep);
        len_front = ins - orig;
        tmp = strncpy(tmp, orig, len_front) + len_front;
        tmp = strcpy(tmp, with) + len_with;
        orig += len_front + len_rep; // move to next "end of rep"
    }
    strcpy(tmp, orig);
    return result;
}
char * Cap(char *string) {
    int i;
    int x = strlen(string); // You want to get the length of the whole string.
    for (i=2;i<x;i++){
        if (isalpha(string[i]) && string[i-1] == ' ' && string[i-2] == '.'){
            // only first letters of a word.
            string[i]= toupper(string[i]);
        }
    }
    return string;
}
void adx_store_data(const char *filepath, const char *data)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "ab");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        fputs(data, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    // char *s = str_replace("aaabaa", 'b', "ccccc");
    //   printf("%s\n", s);
    //  free(s);
    fp = fopen("/home/dac/ClionProjects/replace/temp.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s\n", line);
        str_replace(line, "e", ",");
        line = str_replace(line, " ,", ",");
        line = str_replace(line, ",", ", ");
        line =  str_replace(line, "  ", " ");
        printf("Output: %s",  Cap(line));
        line = Cap(line);
    }
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

/* print some text */
  //  const char *text = "Write this to the file";
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", line);


    fclose(f);
    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Test it:

```
Retrieved line of length 67 :
Hello , there! Hello ,there! A sentence. this should be capitalized
Output: Hello, there! Hello, there! A sentence. This should be capitalized
```

Comment: That logic is a lot different from mine, but it works! Thank you for your time